# Not able to access data from array retrieved in controller to display in view files

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In my cakephp Controller when I retrieve my data by find clause I get this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [Category-name] => Arts
                )

            [Course] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [degree] => UG
                            [course-name] => BSc-Maths
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [degree] => PG
                            [course-name] => MSc Math
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [degree] => UG
                            [course-name] => Bsc Stats
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [degree] => PG
                            [course-name] => Msc-Stats
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [Category-name] => Science and technology
                )

            [Course] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_id] => 2
                            [degree] => UG
                            [course-name] => BSc-CS
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [Category-name] => Commerce
                )

            [Course] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [category_id] => 3
                            [degree] => PG
                            [course-name] => Msc-Finance
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [Category-name] => Law
                )


        )

)
```

I want to show All Courses for a particular Category in ctp file as in form. As For Category Arts there are 4 Courses.

I want to display these 4 Courses for Arts Category.

I am able to Display Categories using the same array.

But not able to display Courses using same array in y ctp file as dropdown in a form.

Is there a way to Access this Courses data? Or Do I have to use different query for to access Courses??

Please I need your help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what your desired result is. Can you add a bit of HTML that demonstrates that you want? It's also recommended to show what you've tried so far (e.g. the part where you can successfully display categories, but also what you've tried for courses), and explain how the result is lacking.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your retrieving query.

Inside the view you can use the array like that:

    $form->input('courses_id', array('type' => 'select','options'=> $courses));

Comment: my retrieving querry is  
$cats = $this->Category->find('all',array('recursive'=>1,'contain'=>array('Course')));

            $this->set('cats',$cats);

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

An improved retrieving Query which only outputs the course names.

```
 $cats = $this->Category->find('all',array(
'conditions'=>array('Category.Category-name'=>'Arts')
'recursive'=>1,
'contain'=>array('Course'),
'fields'=>'Course.course-name'))[0]['Course'];
```

Now the $cats variable should contain an array with 4 entries which can be used in a dropdown select